# SP2010 Search Not Showing Data At Scope and at Site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am seeing crawled content when I look at Crawl Log on Central Admin of SP 2010. And I am also able to see the content in the Crawl log which I have added in one of the site. But when I go to the Site and do a search I am getting nil result. Any help or best practice for configuring the Search in SP 2010, please forward. Thanks

Paddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following steps resolved the issue in our case

1.In IIS Manager, Application pool for all SharePoint services were running under Network Services/Local System/Application Pool Identity. Change these identity with Farm Administrator credentials.
2.In IIS Manager -> Sites -> SharePoint Site/SharePoint Central Admin/SharePoint Web Services (for each) -> Click on .NET Trust Levels – In Actions 
a.Edit Permissions -> Security -> Add Farm Administrator with full control ->Apply.
b.Basic Settings 
i.Test Settings
ii.Connect as -> Specific User -> Set -> Farm Administrator credentials -> ok.
3.Central Administration -> Manage the farm Administrators group -> Settings ->
a.Group Settings -> Set the group owner.
b.Make Default group.
4.Central Administration -> Configure Service Account -> Register new managed account with Farm Administrator credentials -> Select all components one by one to update with Farm Administrator credentials.
5.Crawl the content from Central Administration -> Verify Scope Item count in both Central Administration and Site Collection.

Not sure if this is the correct or the right way to do it but this has resolved the issue. If reader have any better solution please post as answer to this question. Hope this help somebody sometime.

Regards,
Paddy